# Save specific data on external database

Tags: php, mysql, security

Is there a "common way/best practise" to handle information that the user dont want to show us but are nessesary for the program?

My ideas just dont work...

Encryption - We are still the last station and could get the key

A neutral 3. party that hosts the database - No idea if there is something like this, tried to google but didnt find something.

Short info whats behind this: We have developed a quite specific CRM for our businessfield. Its webbased because we travel a lot and need to have it everywhere. Now people saw this and are interested in it but, understandable, are afraid that we can see data that we shouldnt.

Sure we could but dont want so we are looking for a way to guarantee it, or log the access by someone how is neutral or something like this.

Any ideas?

Comment: if it is "nessesary for the program" then you will have to see it, end of story.

Comment: Tell the potential customers that you can offer a self-hosted solution.  You could also offer training.  Make sure your SLA doesn't land you in trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Encryption

It's possible that the data is encrypted and only the end user has the decryption key (e.g. the company shares the decryption key with eachother). However, you won't be able to process any of this data if you do this and it seems like a waste of time.

## Database hosted elsewhere

Your application will still be able to access the database, so this doesn't really work.

## Hosted by the companies themselves

If the companies themselves host the software package, you won't see the data. If there are any issues in the software though, you'll have to have access to their data to fix it.

---

If they don't trust you with being able to see the data, then don't bother as it's going to cause a lot of issues if something goes wrong. Just make sure that you sign the required legal documents / non disclosures to keep your clients happy.

Comment: yeah i thought the same just wanted to ask here in case i didnt think enough "out of the box". If within 24h nobody have an better answer i will just mark this as an answer.